# How to extract a specific string in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to execute this `curl` command using `python`. It retrieves an output like below.

```
* Rebuilt URL to: <dns>
*   Trying <ip>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to escortpersonaladz.com (<ip>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=webdisk.escortpersonaladz.com
*  start date: May  3 02:00:53 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "escortpersonaladz.com" matched cert's "escortpersonaladz.com"
```

How can I extract that particular line `*  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT` from the above output if it is exist?

Comment: Are you sure you want to extract *that specific string*? It is there in the text or not -- use [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) or [`str.index`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) to test.

Comment: These two methods are not working for my scenario. This output is not as same as it looks, sometimes it is one straight line. I want to extract that specific string I have given and print it as well. `str.index` cannot be used because index can be changed over time

Comment: `str.index` locates the string whereever it is, it is not a constant. Are you sure you don't want to do something entirely else, such as "extract the date following `* expire date`"?

Comment: `That is what I want. To extract the substring starting from `* expire date` to `GMT`

Comment: Please [edit] and adjust your question then, as it is different from what you are asking now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

curl_output = '''
* Rebuilt URL to: <dns>
*   Trying <ip>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to escortpersonaladz.com (<ip>) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS Unknown, Certificate Status (22):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=webdisk.escortpersonaladz.com
*  start date: May  3 02:00:53 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "escortpersonaladz.com" matched cert's "escortpersonaladz.com"
'''

match = re.search(r"(\*\s*expire date(.+?))\s*\*", curl_output)
if match:
    desired = match.group(1)
    print(desired)
    #*  expire date: Aug  1 02:00:53 2020 GMT
else:
    print("Not found")
```

The regex matches the string you are looking for by looking between two `*`s that contain the `expire date`. It also accounts for possible spaces before and after. If a match is found, desired string lies in the first group of the match object. In case it is not found, `re.search` will return `None`, so we check and act accordingly.

Comment: @user13456401, That comes from the `print` function. If you want to supress it, change it to `print(desired, end="")`